# how do i make the body fit in the window with HTML and/or CSS?

Tags: html, css, scroll

i'm pretty new to this.
i've tried changing the min-height: 100%;, max-height: 100%;, and height: 100%; on div and just directly on the body, yet it always extends past the bottom of the page, allowing me to scroll the entire page. i want the box i created to scroll on the inside. the only example i can think of what i want it to be like is msx.gay.

here's my CSS:

```
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: blue;
        background-image: url("example.com");
        color: white;
        font-size: 15px;
      }
      .div-1 {
        background-image: url("example.com");
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 68%;
        border: 16px;
        border-color: purple;
        border-style: double;
        word-break: normal;
        overflow: scroll;
        font-family: monospace;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
      }
      a:link {
        color: #9999ff;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      a:visited {
        color: #7777ff;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      a:hover {
        color: #8888ff;
        text-decoration: underline overline;
      }
      a:active {
        color: #ff8888;
        text-decoration: underline overline;
      }
      hr.hr1 {
        border: 1px dotted dimgrey;
      }
      h4 {
        display: inline;
      }
    </style>
```

i apologise if i wrote this question poorly.

Answer (score 0):

The **vh** measure is a unit of measurement that is relative to the height of the viewport. This means that the vh value will be multiplied by the height of the viewport to determine the actual length of the element.
While min-height and max-height are dynamic and depends on the content of that element.

If you want an element (div for ie.) to occupy the full height of your screen you can try :

```
.div-1 {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

There is also dvh (Dynamic viewport height) and svh (Small viewport height) that you can try.

Comment: now my only "issue" is that the background inside the box isn't moving with the rest of the content inside.